# Jomsocila login in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla3.0, jomsocial

In Joomla 3.x I'm using Jomsocial. After first phase registration , it redirect to login page, with 303 error(that one I saw in Networks).

Comment: paste your code here, so people can understand the issue..

Comment: I add this url to my custom Registration page 'component/community/register/login'. It redirect to jomsocial registration phase, which have some steps, after first phase when i click next it redirect me to login page, And in networks I saw my respons  is 303 error.